# Compile error installing highlight package

Tags: macos, r

I am having a problem installing highlight (yes I am aware this package has been removed from CRAN - I tried to install the latest version [here](http://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/highlight/)). I am not positive what the problem is, but it seems like there is an issue with the g++ compiling.

The error I get is

```
> install.packages("~/Downloads/highlight_0.3.2.tar.gz", repos = NULL, type = "source", lib="/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/2.15/Resources/library")
g++ -arch i386 -I/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include -
...
i686-apple-darwin11-llvm-g++-4.2: No such file or directory
i686-apple-darwin11-llvm-g++-4.2: No such file or directory
i686-apple-darwin11-llvm-g++-4.2: No such file or directory
make: *** [highlight.so] Error 1
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘highlight’
```

Session info

```
> sessionInfo()

R version 2.15.2 Patched (2013-01-05 r61562)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin9.8.0/x86_64 (64-bit)

locale:
[1] en_CA.UTF-8/en_CA.UTF-8/en_CA.UTF-8/C/en_CA.UTF-8/en_CA.UTF-8

attached base packages:
[1] tools     stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] parser_0.1      codetools_0.2-8 Rcpp_0.10.2
```

Comment: Do you know that you have the relevant build tools (i.e. g++) installed?  Check the MacOS R FAQ for information on tools for building from source ...

Comment: @BenBolker I have Xcode installed and am able to install most packages from source, but I do get a very similar error with that package. There is a sentence regarding gcc/g++ in the Mac developer page that says" if you want to make it the default compiler (or use sudo gcc_select 4.2)."

Comment: We don't usually put any OS X specialness into these Rcpp-using packages.  Can you install other packages deploying Rcpp?

Comment: @BenBolker Yes, I do believe I have all the build tools installed. For example, will check that over again though

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel Yes, I am able to install Rcpp, Rcpparmadillo, etc.

Comment: I also see this bit in the Rtools page regarding Lion+ versions: "It [gcc] is needed for Xcode 4.2 or higher since Apple has dropped gcc-4.2 from Xcode."

Comment: @DWin in terminal, gcc -v shows I have version 4.2.1

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Scott, I fear that Romain let one or two of his packages decay a little.

We still use highlight in the Rcpp* family so when I needed it recently on another machine, I took the SVN version which still builds fine for me -- svn revision 355 of the highlight repo on R-Forge. You need to install both parser and highlight which build just fine for me on Linux.

Highlight is orphaned so if you feel like adopting it...

Comment: Just installed fine from the SVN repo (on osx). Thanks for the tip! I'm a bit busy with the packages I am currently maintaining - I wish I could.